# Data updating but chart isn't

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, chartkick

I can see my data object changing in Vue dev tools, but the chart isn't updating. This isn't an issue when i'm drawing one thing on the chart but now i'm overlaying two datasets and the chart has lost it's reactivity.

```
<line-chart :library="chartOptions" v-if="photon.sortedBatch.sorted" :data="photon.sortedBatch.rbChannelOverlay"></line-chart>
```

this is what photon.sortedBatch.rbChannelOverlay looks like

```
photon.sortedBatch.rbChannelOverlay =   [{name:'R/B Channel Previous Batch Overlay',data:value.sortedBatch.rbChannel},{name:'R/B Channel',data:value.data.rbChannel}]
```

How would I go about updating the chart? Can I reference the chart and call an update function whenever I add a new data point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Vue function [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) to initially load up your chart with any data you have. Then using a method you can reference the chart and make your updates. Example:

```
  this.chart.data.labels.push(this.count);
  this.chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 5 + 1)) + 5);
  });
    
  this.count = this.count + 1;
  this.chart.update();
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rogerwes/95ovr71u/39/

Otherwise I would suggest looking into https://vue-chartjs.org/ and the examples they provide should give you a good way to update the chart.

Comment: The chart loads correctly i'm not sure where or how to call   this.chart.update(); since the data is getting added through an event listener in my vuex. I am looping through an object called photons`<swiper-slide v-for="(photon,key) in $store.state.photons" :key='key'>`

Comment: See the new updated jsfiddle (there's probably a way to statically do jsfiddle links not sure), but I updated it with a vuex store.

Comment: The main difference is now when mounting, the labels and datasets get assigned with a computed value that returns the store value of the datasets and labels. Those will react when things are added and modified.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to updating the chart was to hold the data in a temporary variable and clear my data variable then set it equal to my temporary variable.